# Recurrence Relation Poker Chips

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I am assuming that the recurrence relation for a) would be $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}+ a_{n-3}$. Correct me if I'm wrong. And I have no idea to what the answer for B is. I would really appreciate it if you provide a detailed explanation on how this problem is solved.

Thanks a lot, really.

Answer (score 1):

For a, given a stack of height $n-1$, you can put either of two colors on top.  For b, a stack of height $n$ can either be a stack of height $n-1$ that you put a blue chip on, or a stack of height $n-2$ that got a blue chip and now you put a red or white on.  Can you make recurrences out of that?

Comment: No I cannot lol

Comment: If $a_{n-1}$ is the number of legal stacks of height $n-1$, and you can put two kinds of chips on top of each one, what is $a_n$?

Comment: why is it that if the height n-1, you can put to colors on top. What happened to the third color.

Comment: You can't put whatever color isn't on top now.  That would make two in a row.

Comment: So wouldn't that make my answer right?

Comment: No.  We have $a_1=3$ because you can have any single chip.  Then $a_2=6$ because we can put two colors on top of any single chip stack.  Similarly, $a_3=12, a_4=24, a_n=2a_{n-1}=3\cdot 2^{n-1}$  Your formula would give $a_4=21$